# MediaStyle notification are not updated properly

Tags: android, notifications

I started using MediaStyle notification. Everything works fine but when I try to update an expanded notification in the lock screen.
In my expanded notification I have four buttons that are shown at the bottom of the notification.

[image: Expanded notification in the lock screen]

If I skip a song the notification is updated. The problem is that it is still shown with the expanded size but with the compat version: only three buttons on the right of the artwork. 
The result is that an empty space is left at the bottom of the notification where there used to be the buttons.

[image]

To show and update the notification I create it by using the new Notification.Builder

```
    final Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle().setMediaSession( mMediaSession.getSessionToken() );

    notificationBuilder.setStyle(style.setShowActionsInCompactView(compactViewButtons));
```

Then I fill all the fields and I use the built notification in the startForeground call for the service.

I tried with both a Nexus 6 and a Nexus 5 with Lollipop.
Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a framework issue:

[Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=88948&can=1&q=MediaStyle%20notification&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)